# cant use Netbeans console after installing new bundle in Symfony2 (error: Symfony2 console must be selected)

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

As a beginner in Symfony Im trying to install and use new bundle in Symfony (DoctrineFixturesBundle) but result in a problem.

I install bundle following the instruction http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html

and after all when adding new project using new-Symfony in Netbeans i got this message:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that composer successfully updated vendor? Search for the bundle you installed into your vendor folder or try `php composer.phar update` again and be sure that there is no error.

Comment: Yes, after installing DoctrineFixturesBundle new Symfony directory differs. Inside Symfony\vendor\doctrine i have now: \data-fixtures and \doctrine-fixtures-bundle

Comment: Have you remove the `src/AppBundle/` directory? If so, remove `new AppBundle\AppBundle()` from the list of your bundle.

Comment: No, `\src\AppBundle` exists. Anyway i will remove `new AppBundle\AppBundle()` and in a moment i will write what is the result.

Comment: My entire \Symfony\composer.json file looks like this: `{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.*"
    }
}`

Comment: @user233352 , that's your error. You have to _add_ the bundle to the dependencies, not replace the whole composer.json. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/installation.html#a-add-composer-dependencies

Comment: @Leggendario wait, but earlier, for the first time i did like you say. I add one line to the existing and result with the same issue.

Comment: uses the previous contents of  `composer.json` then run `composer update`. Finally install `DoctrineFixturesBundle`  with `composer require doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle "2.2.*"`

Comment: @user233352 the removed message are no longer relevant. I think that your problem is with che autoloader generated by composer.

Comment: @user233352, entirely erases your Symfony folder and reinstall it with `composer create-project`. Check if that work well then install `DoctrineFixturesBundle` as I said in my comment. Then add the bundle in `AppKernel.php`

Comment: I start freaking out. Now i cant even normally install Symfony. Last time there was't this: `MAJOR PROBLEM` about `vendor library is missing` from edit 5c picture (first post)

Comment: Ok. After installing new symfony and new doctrine-fixtures-bundle there is no more this ugly fatal error. I can now use console in project with new bundle. Unfortunately again i CAN'T USE CONSOLE INSIDE NETBEANS which is half-success.

Comment: The console is located in `/MyProject/app/console`. Just left-click on the `MyProject`-> Symfony2 -> Run Command.

Comment: problem is solved. Thank you for your time. You are right about path to console, i wrote answer below in the same time you wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetBeans simply uses `<Source Files>/app/console` to run console.

When unzipping Symfony and installing new bundle it's neccesary to zip subfolder of Symfony directory, not root directory.

Unzipped directory structure looks like this

```
symfony2.6.1\Symfony\app\console
symfony2.6.1\Symfony\bin\...
symfony2.6.1\Symfony\src\...
```

My fault was that I zipped root directory: `symfony2.6.1\`, instead of `Symfony\`, or all these subdirectories below `Symfony\`